# Is running the command line "rm -R /media" - safe to do in Ubuntu Linux?

Tags: linux, command-line

I'm trying to clear out an old Ubuntu installation on a different partition (sda5).

I'm currently running Ubuntu from sda1 partition.

Is it safe to do the following (just checking):

```
root@my-laptop:/media/sda5# rm -R /media
```

I'm only asking because:

```
root@my-laptop:/media/sda5# ls -R /media
```

Obviously shows a lot of files referenced in there.

Thanks.

PS: Is there anything that needs saving from that partition??? (I've got the old `/home` directory on a different partition.) I've heard about some `/home` encryption files being stored within `/var` (doesn't apply to me anyway). Are the mysql data there by default? Any other issues?

#### Clarification:

The question was really about: if I delete the contents of sda5 with `rm -R`, do the symbolic links to `media/` also lead to deleting content on those linked partitions (in the same way as `ls -R` **does** give me the files even on the other partition)?

I don't think so, but would like to be assured. I.e. the question is **not** how to delete directories on one partition, **but** whether this can be done using `rm -R` without deleting linked content.

Comment: Why aren't you just reformatting the partition?  Seems to me like it'd be faster and easier in the long run.

Answer (score 0):

It should be safe to remove files WITHIN /media, because they are usually generated when a device is mounted (e.g. inserting a CD-ROM creates /media/cdrom0 in Ubuntu). There may be some folders you created yourself which you will want to keep, but other than that it SHOULD be safe, but take my advice with a pinch of salt - it's an `rm` command, and you must know the forum rule - be wary around posts containing `rm`! :)

Hope this helps

Comment: Actually, I ashamedly went and removed /media via GUI (nautilus), and no problem there... - But I'd rather do it with 'rm' from the terminal in future...

Comment: ah ok. If you do encounter problems, just run "sudo mkdir /media" (minus quotes) should you want to re-create it when Ubuntu hasn't for you :)